# devtools in BlueSky Statistics

Tags: r, devtools

I'm trying to install this data package for the econometrics textbook of Hill et al (from GitHub) and it always returns with an error due to DevTools. BlueSky is using R 3.6.1.

The DevTools installattion shows error after executing:

```
install.packages(c('devtools'), lib='C:/Users/amrof/Documents/R/win-library/3.6')
library(devtools)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for 'devtools' in
> loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
> vI[[j]]):  namespace 'cli' 1.1.0 is being loaded, but >= 2.0.2 is
> required

```
devtools::install_git("https://github.com/ccolonescu/PoEdata")
```

> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),
> versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :    namespace 'cli' 1.1.0 is being loaded,
> but >= 2.0.2 is required In addition: Warning message: In
> memory.limit(17592186044415) : cannot decrease memory limit: ignored
> Error:Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),
> versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :    namespace 'cli' 1.1.0 is being loaded,
> but >= 2.0.2 is required

I have successfully installed using this code in RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there as the error suggesting your cli library version is 1.1.0 but for devtools to install you need to update cli library to 2.0.2. To achieve the same please install your cli library again by the below command

```
install.packages("cli")
```

Then try to install devtools again.